# Open NSPanel with button click in the PDE

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a custom PDE with a button on it and I'd like to show a new NSPanel when I click on it. When I use orderFront or makeKeyAndOrderFront functions, the panel appears but under the print dialog window and has no focus, I can't make anything. When I use runModelForWindow function, the panel appears over the window and seems to be ok, but first this is modal and I'd like panel not to be modal and when I click on the red button to close the panel it disappears but the main print dialog has no focus and I can't make anything with that, even close the app.

Please help me. I'm newbie on Mac programming.

Comment: What is a PDE? Plus, as i understand, you already have "the print dialog", which is, probably, modal. And if it *is* modal, it will have focus priority, so to speak, nothing else can be in focus, when there is a modal panel. Also, Apple guidelines strongly discoruage having several modal windows or panels at the same time.

Comment: PDE - Printing Dialog Extension, also I made a custom pane in the print dialog. You're right print dialog is modal, but I don't want my new panel to be modal. I saw an enxample where this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it:

```
[panel setLevel:CGShieldingWindowLevel()];
[panel setWorksWhenModal:YES];
[panel makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```